# Underestimation of an indicator function

Tags: integration, riemann-integration

I am asked to determine the underestimation of an indicator function on the interval [0,2], defined as follows:
$\int_{0}^{2} \mathbf{1}_{1}\,dx$.

Intuitively, I'd say the answer is 0, since we have one point on the interval and the integral of a point is always zero, however is there a way to work this out more formally?

Edit: and how  would the formal way of the overestimation go exactly?

Comment: What do you mean by underestimation? For rigorous proof, recall the Riemann sum.

Comment: The under- and overestimation of a Riemann-integral is what I meant.